# Lebesgue-Stieltjes Measure associated to $F$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I would like some help here, please.

First is confusing to me the definition of:

Lebesgue-Stieltjes Measure associated to $F$.

I'm reading Folland-Real Analysis, page 35, second paragraph. I do not understand when he "tells" : $\overline{\mu}_{F}$ is just completion of $\mu_{F}$.

So I can not think of the following problem:

(Problem 28-Folland)Let $F$ be increasing and right continuous, and let $\mu_{F}$ be the associated measure. Then $\mu_{F}({a})=F(a)-F(a-)$, $\mu_{F}([a,b))=F(b-)-F(a-)$, $\mu_{F}([a,b])=F(b)-F(a-)$, and $\mu_{F}((a,b))=F(b-)-F(a)$.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: ??? First is confusing to me the definition of:

Lebesgue-Stieltjes Measure associated to F. And further... Problem 28 above.

Comment: The Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure associated to $F$ is the unique Borel measure $\mu_F$ satisfying $\mu_F((a,b])=F(b)-F(a)$ for all $a<b$. Now, to show the properties stated in Problem 28 you need to invoke some _basic_ properties of measures. For instance, to find $\mu_F([a,b])$ you need to write $[a,b]$ in terms of intervals of the form $(a_n,b_n]$ and then use the basic properties to evaluate.